# Serving static files via https in pyramid

Tags: http, https, static, pyramid, url-scheme

i want to serve static files in pyramids via request.static_url('some_file'). Due to several services, my templates got lines like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.static_url('dbas:static/first')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.static_url('websocket:static/second')}"></script>
```

But unfortunately the method static_url() only delivers links with *http* as url_scheme, but i want *https*. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033106/pyramid-debug-toolbar-serving-static-content-over-http-instead-of-https

Comment: Thanks, but i do now want each call via https :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you only need to specify the scheme you want, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.static_url('dbas:static/first', _scheme='https')}"></script>
```

Note: You can also specify _host or _port to define the url. For more info http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.route_url

Comment: But in development i am using http and in production https.

Comment: You can pass an enviroment variable defined in your setup.ini (for example development.ini and production.ini), like myproject.scheme = http and pass to the template to make it dynamic like (settings.get('myproject.scheme', 'http'))

Answer (score 6):

You can add url_scheme param to your configuration file (separated by environment) like that:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6500
url_scheme = https
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it's correct, per the wsgi docs here: https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/definitions.html#wsgi-environ-keys

Comment: Yes @Jonno_FTW, I don't know why it is downvoted too.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed for https://stackoverflow.com/a/61370594/358532!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but since I struggled a bit with that one, I thought I could give some info.

In the scenario where your have

> 1-A reverse proxy -> 2-A service running the pyramid App -> 3-The pyramid app code

3- Pyramid generates the url using the *request.environ['wsgi.url_scheme']*

2- The service running the app should set the wsgi_url_scheme. Gunicorn for example set this attribute if the reverse proxy set the *X-Forwarded-Proto* and if the reverse proxy ip is listed in the *forwarded_allow_ips*

1- The reverse proxy should set the *X-Forwarded-Proto* header

In the case of gunicorn + nginx

For nginx set the header add the following in the SSL part

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

For gunicorn the IP address of the nginx reverse proxy should be specified in the command line as described in the [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#forwarded-allow-ips)

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers=4 --timeout=60 --paster /config/myapp.ini --forwarded-allow-ips 1.2.3.4`